# tableview scroll choppy on iphone 6s

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have 2 projects and have recently noticed that scrolling the tableview is not smooth. Its not horrible, but not as nice as it could be. Running the projects on my iphone 4s is perfectly smooth. My cell setup does have 2 images and a date formatter but the fact that it runs fine on the 4s is perplexing. Has anyone else encountered this issue. I have looked online and not found any solution. I have tried taking out items here one at a time but with no luck.

```
    var current : message
    var subject : String
    var body : String

    var status = "sent"
    if sentorreceived == "received" {
        status = Array.messages[indexPath.row].isread
        current = Array.messages[indexPath.row]

    } else {
        status = sentArray.messages[indexPath.row].isread
        current = sentArray.messages[indexPath.row]
    }

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! inboxcell

    subject = current.subject
    body = current.body
    let thecorrectdate = self.datehelper(current.date)
    cell.bodyfield.text = body
    cell.subjectfield.text = subject
    cell.datefield.text = thecorrectdate
    cell.fromfield.text = current.from

    if current.messagetype == "PAGE" {
        cell.priority.hidden = false
    } else {
        cell.priority.hidden = true
    }
    if current.attachments.count == 0 {
        cell.paperclip.hidden = true
    } else {
        cell.paperclip.hidden = false
    }
    var status = "sent"
    if sentorreceived == "received" {
        status = Array.messages[indexPath.row].isread
    } else {
        status = ArraySent.messages[indexPath.row].isread
    }
    var imagestring : String?

    switch status {
        case "SENT":
        imagestring = "SentMessageiOSIcon"

        case "DELIVERED":
        imagestring = "DeliveredMessageiOSIcon"

        case "REPLIED":
        imagestring = "RepliedSentMessageiOSIcon"

        case "READ":
        imagestring = "ReadMessageSentiOSIcon"

        case "FAILED":
        imagestring = "FailedMessageiOSIcon"

        case "PAGEROFF":
        imagestring = "OffMessageiOSIcon"

        default:
        imagestring = "SentMessageiOSIcon"
    }

    if sentorreceived == "sent" {

        let theimage = UIImage(named: imagestring!)
        cell.envelope.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
        cell.envelope.clipsToBounds = true
        cell.envelope.image = theimage

    } else {

        if status == "DELIVERED" {
            let theimage = UIImage(named: "UnreadMessageiOSIcon")
            cell.envelope.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
            cell.envelope.clipsToBounds = true
            cell.envelope.image = theimage
        } else {
            let theimage = UIImage(named: "ReadMessageiOSIcon")
            cell.envelope.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
            cell.envelope.clipsToBounds = true
            cell.envelope.image = theimage
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: It is impossible to know what could be wrong without more context.  Please post your table view code.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, it had nothing to do with code. I needed to run an Update on the phone from 9.0.2 to 9.1.